# Read HTML tags from file and displaying them in terminal correctly

Tags: c++, html, enums, terminal, escaping

I am a beginner in C++ with with a rough understanding of JAVA. I am trying to read a HTML file which looks like this.

```
<red>Red <dim>dim and red</dim> back to red</red>

<blue>Blue <underline>underlined blue <dim>dim</dim> underlined blue</underline>
and <cyan>cyan</cyan> and blue again</blue>
```

This is a very small snippet of the code I am using. An example of my issue is, I cannot figure out how to clear the formatting for dim and keep the text red until the end tag is reached(1st line of code above).

```
void print_well_formed_file(ifstream& ifs) {
Lexer lexer; Token tok;
stack<string> tags;
string fstring;
term_colors_t scancolor;
term_attrib_t scanattrib;

while(getline(ifs,fstring)){
    lexer.set_input(fstring);
    while(lexer.has_more_token()){
    tok = lexer.next_token();
        switch(tok.type){
            case TAG:
                if(tok.value[0] != '/'){
                    tags.push(tok.value);
                    if(tok.value == "red")
                        scancolor = RED;
                    else if(tok.value == "green")
                        scancolor = GREEN;
                    else if(tok.value == "yellow")
                        scancolor = YELLOW;
                    else if(tok.value == "blue")
                        scancolor = BLUE;
                    else if(tok.value == "magenta")
                        scancolor = MAGENTA;
                    else if(tok.value == "cyan")
                        scancolor = CYAN;
                    else if(tok.value == "dim")
                        scanattrib = DIM;
                    else if(tok.value == "underline")
                        scanattrib = UNDERLINE;
                    else if(tok.value == "bright")
                        scanattrib = BRIGHT;
                    cout << term_cc(scancolor, DEFAULT_COLOR, scanattrib);

                }else if(tags.top() == tok.value.substr(1)){
                    tags.pop();
                    //THIS IS WHERE THE END TAGS WOULD BE PROCESSED.
                }

            break;
            case IDENT:
                cout << tok.value << " ";
            break;
            case ERRTOK:
                cout << "Syntax Error: " << tok.value;
                noerror = false;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

And the functions being implemented below.

```
std::string term_cc(term_colors_t fg=DEFAULT_COLOR, 
                term_colors_t bg=DEFAULT_COLOR, 
                term_attrib_t attr=DEFAULT_ATTRIB);

std::string term_bg(term_colors_t bg=DEFAULT_COLOR);
std::string term_fg(term_colors_t fg=DEFAULT_COLOR);
std::string term_attrib(term_attrib_t attrib=DEFAULT_ATTRIB);
std::string term_clear();
```

I have tried using the stack commands in the else loop but recieve a segmentation fault while running.

I know what I am asking is relatively vague but I am using terminal escape commands and enumerated types to mock the way HTML is read for terminal.

```
enum term_attrib_t {
DEFAULT_ATTRIB = '0',
BRIGHT    = '1',
DIM       = '2',
UNDERLINE = '4',
BLINK     = '5',
REVERSE   = '7',
HIDDEN    = '8'
};

// the colors, background or foreground
enum term_colors_t {
BLACK   = '0',
RED     = '1',
GREEN   = '2',
YELLOW  = '3',
BLUE    = '4',
MAGENTA = '5',
CYAN    = '6',
WHITE   = '7',
DEFAULT_COLOR = '9'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file looks more like an XML file rather than HTML. Html parser for any HTML file around is extremely complex. You will neither find it nor write it yourself in any reasonable time.

I would recommend you to browse internet for XML readers. There are dozens of them out. Finally I have my own that I can in general share.